# Import file with stored procedure into existing database in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import

I have database in Microsoft SQL Server. I also have a file with a stored procedure from another database. How I can add this stored procedure to my database? There is piece of this procedure. When i'm trying to execute this procedure in my database `[dbo].[unefficient_block]` underlined by red color in managment studio. I can't run this procedure, because have errror

> Invalid object name 'dbo.unefficient_block'.

```
USE [rum]
GO  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[unefficient_block]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @calls int
DECLARE @msisdn nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @status int
DECLARE @warn_sms int
declare @lang int

declare cur1  CURSOR FOR 
select nds, count(*) as calls 
from rum.dbo.unefficient_calls
where nds not in (select phone from rum.dbo.huly h) 
-- and nds not in (select msisdn COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from rum.dbo.unefficient_status s where status=1) 
group by nds
```

Comment: Fire up SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your database in question, open the file with the stored procedure, run it to create the stored procedure in your database - done!

Comment: Change ALTER PROCEDURE to CREATE PROCEDURE and make sure the USE points to the correct database.